# How to setup socket connection to virtualbox virtual machine in host-only mode?

Tags: python, sockets, virtualbox

My host OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and the VM OS is CentOS 7.9. The VM network is on host-only mode. I don't know why the socket connection from host to VM always fail.
[image: VM network setting]

Here's the python code of server running on VM:

```
import socket            
 
s = socket.socket()        
print ("Socket successfully created")
 
port = 12345
s.bind(('192.168.56.103', port))        
print ("socket binded to %s" %(port))

s.listen(5)    
print ("socket is listening")           

while True:
  c, addr = s.accept()    
  print ('Got connection from', addr )
  c.send('Thank you for connecting'.encode())
  c.close()
  break
```

Here's the python code of client running on host:

```
import socket            

s = socket.socket()        
port = 12345               
s.connect(('192.168.56.103', port))
 
print (s.recv(1024).decode())
s.close()
```

The server runs fine but the client keeps reporting
`OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host`.
The host and VM can ping and ssh each other without a problem. I'm sure the port is not occupied by another process on both sides. Is there a way to let the host connect to VM with socket in host-only mode?

Comment: If ping and SSH from host to VM work, then the general connectivity is there. If a specific port does not work then likely because the firewall on the target machine (in the VM) blocks it.

Answer (score 0):

Steffen Ullrich answered my question in the comments. Here's what I found for unblocking a port on CentOS 7

Comment: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-open-a-ports-in-centos-rhel-7/